# Як правильно: "гамільтонова графа" чи "гамільтонового графа"

Tags: прикметники

У теорії графів є таке поняття як [гамільтонів граф/шлях/цикл](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84). Як правильно: **гамільтонова** графа/шляху/циклу чи **гамільтонового** графа/шляху/циклу. Зі слів знайомої лінгвістки, варіант "гамільтонова" у мене через вплив російської.

Comment: Тільки "графУ". Бо "графА" - це буде про людину з титулом граф:) [Дзвона чи дзвону](http://rodovyi-vidminok.wikidot.com/gh)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko [словник УЛІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) з вами не погоджується. Він подає закінчення -а в обох випадках: істота, математичний об'єкт

Comment: я більше звик довіряти спеціалізованому словнику з цього питання. Можливо, тут нам розкажуть правду: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%90-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%a3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Коротка відповідь: все складно, єдиної думки нема.

---

Подібні запитання виникають унаслідок складності з визначенням, якою частиною мови є згадане слово. Власне, є два варіанти:

1. **Присвійний прикметник**, як-то *братів*, — тобто, у даному випадку, «шлях, який належить Гамільтону»;
2. **Прикметниковий іменник**, як-то *лютий* (місяць) або *черговий* (той, хто на посту або стежить за порядком) — у даному випадку, «шлях, який названо на честь Гамільтона»;

Наприклад, багато складнощів викликає [відмінювання слова *Мукачеве*](http://zakarpattya.net.ua/News/142606-Movoznavtsi-pravylno-pysaty-%E2%80%93-Mukacheve-a-vidminiaty-%E2%80%93-Mukacheva-Mukachevu-u-Mukachevi), але там ще втручається граматичний рід (чоловічий або середній).

---

#### Прикметники

Правопис закінчень відмінюваних прикметників [виглядає так](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par68):

```
Н.  братів
Р.  братов-ого
Д.  братов-ому
Зн. = Н. або Р.
Ор. братов-им
М. братов-ому (-ім)
```

---

#### Іменники

Допіру все логічно і не викликає заперечень.
Але у тому ж документі трохи нижче окремо наголошується (emphasis mine):

> Прикметникові іменники типу *будівничий*, *лютий* (місяць), *подорожній* тощо **відмінюються як прикметники**: *до будівничого, будівничі, з будівничими*; *лютого, в лютому*.
> Пор. у сполученнях: Сьогодні п’яте лютого й П’ятого лютого 1988 року.

Таким чином, сайт «Український правопис», фактично, вважає, що прикметникові іменники відмінюються за правилами прикметників, і тому — **гамільтонового**.

У цю схему також вписується більш розповсюджене *«Шевченк**ів** твір — Шевченк**ового** твору»*, а не «Шевченкова».

---

Щоправда, можна легко навести контрприклад — *Бердич**ів** - Бердич**ева***, але якби це був *«Бердичів шлях, міст»*, то було б *«Бердичевого шляху, мосту»*.

Також, в Інтернеті на цілком поважних сайтах можна часто знайти протилежний варіант:

- [«Відшукання **гамільтонова шляху** на неповнодоступному стохастичному графі»](http://www.hups.mil.gov.ua/periodic-app/article/13403/ukr) — сайт Харківського національного університету Повітряних Сил імені Івана Кожедуба;
- **«Гамільтонова шляху»** згадується у статті [Дискретна математика](http://www.imath.kiev.ua/%7Edrozd/Discrete.pdf) (PDF) — сайт Мехмату КНУ ім. Т.Г. Шевченка;
- [Ще декілька джерел із пошуку](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85%D1%83%22);

Comment: Це прикметник. *Який* граф? Гамільтонів.

Comment: @thorn, вірно. А місяць *який?* — лютий. Все — унаслідок того, що окрім «чистих» частин мови як-то іменників, прикметників тощо, існує велике різнобарв'я частин мови, які поєднують риси декількох частин мови. Наприклад, *віддієприкметникові іменники*. Тобто, для того, щоб однозначно класифікувати це слово саме як прикметник, варто навести поважні джерела. Інакше легко заплутатися.

Comment: Як взагалі може спасти на думку, що це слово може бути іменником? Прикметник стає іменником (субстантивується), коли він вживається самостійно, виконуючи синтаксичні функції, притаманні іменникам (підмет, додаток тощо), позначає не ознаку предмета, а сам предмет.

Comment: У цьому випадку ми маємо звичайне словосполучення типу прикметник + іменник. Таке саме, як синє море, старе місто тощо. Чим, на вашу думку, так відрізняються "гамільтонів граф" і "синє море", що у вас виникають сумніви?

Comment: Вчора була нагода запитати у лінгвістки, вона сказала, що правильно Гамільтонового, а Гамільтонова - це якійсь наподібок з російської.

Comment: Так і є: *братового зошита*, *Ярославового Валу*, *Протасового яру*, *гамільтонового графа*... Правила чинного правопису в цій частині (відмінювання прикметників) цілком однозначні.

Comment: @thorn гадаю ви могли б свої коментарі оформити як відповідь.