# Родовий відмінок слова "граф" (математичний термін): графА чи графУ?

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Згідно зі спеціалізованим словником [Дзвона чи дзвону](http://rodovyi-vidminok.wikidot.com/gh) правильно "графу", згідно зі [словником УЛІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) - "графа" (на жаль не знаю, як отримати посилання на конкретне слово).

Як правильно?

Comment: Пов'язане питання: [Як правильно: “гамільтонова графа” чи “гамільтонового графа”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1341/69).

Comment: Цікаво було б дізнатися, за якою логікою виник варіант "графу". Я б писав *-а* за аналогією до інших абстрактних математичних об'єктів: *вектор*, *тензор*, назви геометричних фігур, а також власне *об'єкт*.

Answer (score 5):

Цікаво, що якщо шукати у словнику УЛІФ отак: [http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=граф](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84)

То він видає два релевантні результати (третій — "графа́"):

> **граф 1**  – іменник чоловічого роду, істота
>
> ```
> відмінок       однина              множина
> родовий        гра́фа               гра́фів
> ```

та

> **граф 2** – іменник чоловічого роду
>
> ```
> відмінок       однина              множина
> родовий        гра́фа, гра́фу        гра́фів
> ```

Тобто, титул "граф" у родовому відмінку — завжди "графа", а інші вжитки — як "графа" так і "графу".

## Але

Якщо шукати через звичайний інтерфейс, то словник уточнює що "**граф 1**" це "титулована особа", а "**граф 2**" — "математичний об'єкт" і варіант родового відмінка "графу" не наводить в жодній статті, звідки виникає питання — з якого словника беруться посилання за таким хакнутим посиланням, бо очевидно що це якась інша версія словника, що відрізняється від того, що доступний через звичайний користувацький інтерфейс.